# Support maximum screen aspect ratio without hard-coded ratio?

Tags: android

In principle, my app is agnostic of the aspect ratio of the screen (as it should be for an Android app). Now, the [recommended](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html) practice is to manually add

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="ratio_float" />
```

into the manifest because of the trend of smartphone screens with aspect ratio higher than the default supported ratio of 1.86. My question is, instead of setting a hard-coded ratio eg 2.1, is there a better way to tell the Android that *I don't care what is the max aspect ratio*?

If no, can I set an arbitrarily high value such as 3.1 or even 5.1? Is it safe to do so? I'm not talking about the exotic weird screen sizes but the *mainstream* future screens and the best practice to handle this in future. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David's answer is correct if we want to support high aspect ratio screens on API < 24 (before Nougat). Going forward, however, the documentation says that `android:resizeableActivity` is true by default for API 24 and above. That means the app is automatically free-form in future (correct me if I am wrong). Considering that Galaxy S8 already ships with Nougat out of the box, I'd say there is no need to worry if your app is OK with free-form style.

EDIT: If your targetSdkVersion is < 24 then you should use David's solution because free-form will not automatically kick in for phones OS with Nougat (or higher) installed.

Comment: The documentation talks about _targetSdk_, for which it defaults to true on `>= 24`. This is not to be confused with the phone OS. This is a value the developer sets uniquely for every application. Unless you target 24+ you _will_ have to set the manifest attribute.

Comment: Yes, I finally understood what you meant. Personally, this is not a problem for me because I have already set targetSdk>24. Moreover, I look for the best long-term solution if there needs to be one. But I add some clarification to emphasize your point.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html) they also hint on `resizableActivity`.

> **Note:** if you don't set a value, and [android:resizeableActivity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#configuring) is not true, then the maximum aspect ratio defaults to 1.86 (roughly 16:9) and your app will not take advantage of the extra screen space.

So you should add `android:resizeableActivity="true"` to your Activity or Application. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#configuring) also states

> If this attribute is set to true, the activity can be launched in split-screen and freeform modes.

And it seems like *freeform mode* is what you care about.

Comment: I read the documentation more carefully and it says that API 24 or higher `android:resizeableActivity"` attribute is true by default. Considering that Galaxy S8 already has Android 7.0 installed out of the box, I think there is no need do anything. The future is bright after all.

Comment: Watch out! _If your app_ **targets** _API level 24 or higher_ So this is not about the phone OS version, this is about the target sdk of your app